# localstorage not persisting on node-webkit

Tags: javascript, local-storage, node-webkit, nw.js, web-storage

I'm working on a NW.js (Node-Webkit) app and I noticed that the local storage objects I'm using aren't persisting.

The problem is simple I guess, data gets saved in a local storage object then when a `window.open` window is opened it should print that saved data, but when I open the dev tools I notice only the name of the local storage object which is "view" exists but the value is empty (`undefined`). What's irritating is that it works perfectly well from the browser (chrome, firefox, etc..).

This is my code

```js
var count = 3600,
  counter,
  seconds,
  minutes,
  startGameBtn = document.getElementById('start-game-btn'),
  slaveScreen = document.getElementById('slave-screen');
//When this button is pressed a count down starts from 1 hour
startGameBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  GameplayStatus = true;

  if (GameplayStatus) {
    this.disabled = true;
  }

  function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count == -1) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      return;
    }
    seconds = count % 60;
    minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    minutes %= 60;

    masterScreen.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    localStorage.setItem('view', minutes + ":" + seconds);
  }
});

//In order to recognize the new window and be able to target it
if (location.hash) {
  setInterval(function() {
    //should print the timer in the new window constantly. Works perfectly on the browser but doesn't display anything on node-webkit. The key exists but the value is empty (undefined)
    slaveScreen.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('view');
  }, 50);
```

Comment: Please submit an issue. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I fixed it and it was totally my bad. There's nothing wrong with it. The mistake I did was that when I used `window.open` I used 'file:///C:/username/path/to/file..' in the URL when I was only supposed to enter `index.html`